# How to get full stdout from a node.js child_process that spawns another process recursively?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to `spawn` a child process like this:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const child = spawn("python run.py", {
  detached: true,
  shell: true,
})
```

The problem is, the `run.py` then calls another process called `child.py`.

I noticed that when I listen to the `child`'s stdout, it prints all the log messages in the `python run.py` process, but not the `python child.py`, which is called interanlly by `run.py`.

So my question is, how do you capture all the STDOUT from child processes recursively?

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate `run.py` python determines where stdio from `child.py` goes.

Here's some JS to run the python, setting specific stdio options

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process')

console.log('python.js')

const child = spawn("./run.py", {
  stdio: [ 'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'pipe' ]
})
child.stdio[3].on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('fd3: %s', data)
})
```

The [stdio option](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio), `inherit` is used to pass through the node processes stdin, stdout, stderr. This setup is not specific to your question, but I've included it as an example of what `run.py` will do with it's child.

The 4th element `pipe` opens an extra channel as file descriptor `3` (After descriptor 0/1/2 are used for stdin/stdout/stderr.

The intermediate `run.py` python then chooses where stdio goes for its `child.py` processes.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from subprocess import Popen
from os import fdopen

print('run.py')

# `Popen` defaults to `inherit`, so stdout/stderr from child.py will
# be written to the `run.py` processes stdout/sterr
Popen(['./child.py'])

# Second child, the file descriptor created in node will be used for stdout
pipe = fdopen(3)
Popen(['./child.py'], stdout=pipe)
```

The child script outputs as normal.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
print('child.py')
```

When run:

```
$ node python.js
python.js
run.py
child.py
fd3: child.py
```

Comment: Thank you. But this looks like I have to have control over the child.py. What if I want to be able to just call whatever child process and capture all their stdout without having any control over their code to redirect the stdout?

Comment: It's possible with lower level tools on linux like `strace` can monitor or gdb can modify running processes. I'm not sure there is a normal mechanism to reach in from node and copy the content of pipes fd 1,2 of child processes. It might be a bit easier if `run.py` is writing the output to a file.